# Replacing entries in column in specific cases with content of a different column in the same row in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (dataM1) with multiple columns and over 16k of rows. Two of the columns are age and education. Education is measured by the age until one went to school.One of the entries in education  is "still studying". In the case of "still studying" I want it to replaced by the age of that specific entry.

Input:

```
age     education

25         10
30          5
12    still studying
15          6
21    still studying
```

desired Output:

```
age     education
25         10
30          5
12         12
15          6
21         21
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the package `dplyr`:

If the `education` column is "still studying", replace it with `age`, otherwise, keep the values in `education`.

```
library(dplyr)

# your data
df <- data.frame(age = c(25, 30, 12, 15, 21), 
                 education = c("10", "5", "still studying", "6", "still studying"))

df %>% mutate(education = ifelse(education == "still studying", age, education))

  age education
1  25        10
2  30         5
3  12        12
4  15         6
5  21        21
```